# Generate increasing random number rails

Tags: ruby

I've a random number generator code:

```
5.times.map { [*0..9].sample }.join.to_i
```

It gives me random numbers like `63832, 42337, 34998`. As you can see that they are completely random, but how to make than I would get only in an increasing way? Not `63832, 42337, 34998`, but `34998, 42337, 63832` (this is just an example, Ideally I would get smth like `00[number]` => `0025`, where 25 is a random number which was generated.

Hope my explanation is understandable :)

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: BTW, your example code is equivalent to `rand(100_000)`

Comment: Do you need a specific number of sorted random numbers? Or do you need a method that returns a random number with the condition it is bigger than the last random number? What if the first random number return is 99999? What do you expect your method to do next?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the current / last random number, you can generate a larger one by simply *adding* a random number to it, e.g:

```
def generate(base = 0)
  base + rand(1_000..10_000)
end

number = generate          #=> 9635
number = generate(number)  #=> 17761
number = generate(number)  #=> 22082
number = generate(number)  #=> 31061
```

Each number is 1,000 to 10,000 larger than its predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach, if you want to generate all random numbers *within a known range*:

```
[*1..10000].sample(5).sort
  # => [602, 5608, 7912, 8384, 8714]
```

However, this only works if you want to fetch all random numbers upfront, rather than continuously being able to generate new ones which are larger.

It's also not a good approach if your upper limit is very big - e.g. this will freeze your system and need to be cancelled:

```
[*1..10000000000].sample(5).sort
```

...But in that case, since the numbers are so huge, you can surely get away with the tiny risk of having a collision:

```
5.times.map{ rand(1..10000000000) }.sort
  # => [460188573, 555213355, 3576967759, 3994239233, 9570165205]
```